# Will Apple Rejects App with Key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in Plist is set to YES

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have a query from Apple documentation.

I am going to add key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in my app's plist.

Will Apple reject my app due to this key?

Or is there any better way to kill the app when it moves in background?

Comment: Why would apple reject the app for using a publicly available and documented feature?

Comment: Is there a way for me to call UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend programatically?  Can you suggest me a way to kill application when it goes in background for a particular scenario. Also please consider I want to upload the application on iTunesconnect, so worried Apple won't reject it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be rejected.

[UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23)

> Apps linked against iOS SDK 4.0 or later can include this key and set
>   its value to YES to prevent being automatically opted-in to background
>   execution and app suspension. When the value of this key is YES, the app is terminated and purged from memory instead of moved to the background. If this key is not present, or is set to NO, the app moves to the background as usual.